# Scala (Spark) .txt to .csv

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, txt

I've got both `.txt` an d `.dat` files with structure:

```
Number    Date     Time         Nns     Ans Nwe     Awe     
1   22.07.17 08:00:23   12444   427 8183    252     
2   22.07.17 08:00:24   13  312 9   278     
3   22.07.17 08:00:25   162 1877    63  273     
4   22.07.17 08:00:26   87  400 29  574     
5   22.07.17 08:00:27   72  349 82  2047        
6   22.07.17 08:00:28   79  294 63  251     
7   22.07.17 08:00:29   35  318 25  248
```

I can't translate it to `.csv` by using `Spark/Scala`.

```scala
  val data = spark
      .read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema","true")
      .csv() /.text /.textfile
```

doesn't work!

Please help.

Here s file - https://github.com/CvitoyBamp/overflow

Comment: Also i ve tried to do .trim or .replaceAll spaces.

Comment: what's the exception u'r getting?

Comment: You'll probably have to configure the field separator. Look at the docs for the [`csv` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

Comment: you don't need spark for this. just use something like sed to replace spaces with commas

Comment: i am expecting to have EXCEL-like table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps, it's wotking fine for me with your A.txt test file

First, read the File as usual:

```
val df  = spark.read.csv("A.txt")
```

get the headers from the first row and zip them with index

```
val headers = df.first.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].flatMap(_.split("\\s+")).zipWithIndex
```

**RESULT**

```
 headers: Seq[(String, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((Number,0), (Date,1), (Time,2), (Nns,3), (Ans,4), (Nwe,5), (Awe,6))
```

Then foldLeft the headers retrieving the item indicated by the index (second item in each header element) and assigning it the name of the column (first item in each header element)

Also drop the undesired columns and filter the row containing the headers value

```
headers.foldLeft(df.withColumn("tmp", split($"_c0", "\\s+")))
    ((acc, elem) => acc.withColumn(elem._1, $"tmp".getItem(elem._2)))
       .drop("_c0", "tmp")
       .filter("Number <> 'Number'")
```

**RESULT**

```
+------+--------+--------+-----+----+----+----+
|Number|    Date|    Time|  Nns| Ans| Nwe| Awe|
+------+--------+--------+-----+----+----+----+
|     1|22.07.17|08:00:23|12444| 427|8183| 252|
|     2|22.07.17|08:00:24|   13| 312|   9| 278|
|     3|22.07.17|08:00:25|  162|1877|  63| 273|
|     4|22.07.17|08:00:26|   87| 400|  29| 574|
|     5|22.07.17|08:00:27|   72| 349|  82|2047|
|     6|22.07.17|08:00:28|   79| 294|  63| 251|
|     7|22.07.17|08:00:29|   35| 318|  25| 248|
|     8|22.07.17|08:00:30|   10| 629|  12| 391|
|     9|22.07.17|08:00:31|   58| 511|  67| 525|
|    10|22.07.17|08:00:32|   72| 234|  29| 345|
|    11|22.07.17|08:00:33|  277|1181|  38| 250|
|    12|22.07.17|08:00:34|   40| 268|  31| 292|
|    13|22.07.17|08:00:35|   16| 523|  10| 368|
|    14|22.07.17|08:00:36|  319|1329| 143| 703|
|    15|22.07.17|08:00:37|  164| 311| 124| 352|
|    16|22.07.17|08:00:38|   62| 320| 116| 272|
|    17|22.07.17|08:00:39|  223| 356| 217|1630|
|    18|22.07.17|08:00:40|   50|1659|  94|1611|
|    19|22.07.17|08:00:41|   34| 431|  26| 587|
|    20|22.07.17|08:00:42|    0|   0|   5| 277|
+------+--------+--------+-----+----+----+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Also, a solution close to the one from the other answer

You can load your data as a String Dataset

```
  val stringDF = spark.read.textFile("Downloads/A.txt").map(_.replaceAll("\\s+", " "))
```

And then

```
val data = spark
  .read
  .option("header", true)
  .option("sep", " ")
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv(cleaned)
  .drop("_c7")
```

RESULT

```
+------+--------+--------+-----+----+----+----+
|Number|    Date|    Time|  Nns| Ans| Nwe| Awe|
+------+--------+--------+-----+----+----+----+
|     1|22.07.17|08:00:23|12444| 427|8183| 252|
|     2|22.07.17|08:00:24|   13| 312|   9| 278|
|     3|22.07.17|08:00:25|  162|1877|  63| 273|
|     4|22.07.17|08:00:26|   87| 400|  29| 574|
|     5|22.07.17|08:00:27|   72| 349|  82|2047|
|     6|22.07.17|08:00:28|   79| 294|  63| 251|
|     7|22.07.17|08:00:29|   35| 318|  25| 248|
|     8|22.07.17|08:00:30|   10| 629|  12| 391|
|     9|22.07.17|08:00:31|   58| 511|  67| 525|
|    10|22.07.17|08:00:32|   72| 234|  29| 345|
|    11|22.07.17|08:00:33|  277|1181|  38| 250|
|    12|22.07.17|08:00:34|   40| 268|  31| 292|
|    13|22.07.17|08:00:35|   16| 523|  10| 368|
|    14|22.07.17|08:00:36|  319|1329| 143| 703|
|    15|22.07.17|08:00:37|  164| 311| 124| 352|
|    16|22.07.17|08:00:38|   62| 320| 116| 272|
|    17|22.07.17|08:00:39|  223| 356| 217|1630|
|    18|22.07.17|08:00:40|   50|1659|  94|1611|
|    19|22.07.17|08:00:41|   34| 431|  26| 587|
|    20|22.07.17|08:00:42|    0|   0|   5| 277|
+------+--------+--------+-----+----+----+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving the case!
I've been struggling all day with .replaceAll .trim .split
Really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer so anyone with the same issue can find it easily

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```scala
val text = spark.read.textFile(pathToFile)
val cleaned = text.map(_.replaceAll(" +", " ").trim)
val data = spark
  .read
  .option("header", true)
  .option("sep", " ")
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv(cleaned)
```

It will first read the file as simple strings, line by line. Then it replaces every sequence of 1 or more spaces with exactly 1 space, and then tries to parse the result as csv with a single space as separator. One thing you have to be aware of is that when one of your fields contains a sequence of multiple spaces they will also be replaced by a single space.

Comment: Thanks for helping! But it s also doesn t works =( Spark creating Null values. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwj8I.png

Comment: @Cvitoybamp When I add `trim` to the cleaning step I get no null values anymore with the example you posted. Did you use replace**All**? Also your actual file seems to contain an extra unnamed field.

Comment: Sorry, my Bad.Thank you so much for solving the case! I've been struggling all day with .replaceAll .trim .split Really appreciate it!